# php LDAP Invalid credentials

Tags: php, authentication, ldap

My code is:

```
$user = 'test';
$password = 'testpass';
$host = '10.1.1.1';
$port = 389;
$basedn = 'dc=ci,dc=mycompany,dc=com';
$group = 'Users';
$ldaprdn = 'uid=test,dc=ci,dc=mycompany,dc=com';

$ad = ldap_connect("ldap://$host", $port);
if ($ad) {
    echo "Connected" . "<br/>";
} else {
    echo ldap_error($ad) . "<br/>";
}
ldap_set_option($ad, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ad, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

//  $ldapBind = ldap_bind($ad, "{$user}@{$domain}", $password); // 1.
//  $ldapBind = ldap_bind($ad, $user, $password); // 2.
    $ldapBind = ldap_bind($ad, $ldaprdn, $password); // 3.
//  $ldapBind = ldap_bind($ad, null, null); // 4.

if ($ldapBind) {
    echo "Binded" . "<br/>";
} else {
    echo ldap_error($ad) . "<br/>";
}
```

Now I use the comment line "3", get:

```
Connected
Invalid credentials
```

If use the comment line "1" or "2", get:

```
Connected
Invalid DN syntax
```

If use the comment line "4" (this is anonymouse), get:

```
Connected
Binded
```

This is developing under Ubuntu 12.

**Why I get Invalid credentials error from comment line "3"? How to bind with authentication correctly?
Thanks in advance!**

Comment: My environment is Ubuntu 12

Answer (score 6):

The `ldap_bind` function appears to require a **DN**, not an **RDN**, no matter what the doc says. If this is the case, then:

- Number 1. `{$user}@{$domain}` is not a correctly formatted DN, hence: `Invalid DN syntax`
- Number 2: `test` is not a correctly formatted DN, hence: `Invalid DN syntax`

For information on the string representation of the formatting of **DN**, see [RFC4514](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4514)

### verify with known good tool

As far as I can tell, Number 3 is the only correct one of the four that are provided. The Directory Server has indicated in the BIND response that it was unable to verify that the provided password `testpass` matched the password that is stored in its database. In this case, I recommend checking the password using a known good tool like `ldapsearch`.

```
ldapsearch -h hostname -p port              \
    -D 'uid=test,dc=ci,dc=mycompany,dc=com' \
    -w 'testpass' -s base '(&)' 1.1
```

This `ldapsearch` BINDs to the directory as 'uid=test,dc=ci,dc=mycompany,dc=com' using password `testpass` and retrieves the **DN** of the `uid=test` entry. If this fails with "invalid credentials" error, then there are these possibilities:

- `testpass` is not the correct password
- some directory servers can be configured to set the result code to "invalid credentials" no matter what the true error is. The reason for this is to withhold information from an attacker
- the `uid=test` entry does not exist. The bullet point above explains this would result in an "invalid credentials". There is no point in telling an attacker that an entry does not exist - that would provide the attacker with additional information (he has one less DN to try).

### jargon and LDAP-speak

In the interest of using the correct jargon:

- `$ldaprdn` is not an RDN, it's a DN. RDNs are components of DNs

### see also

- [LDAP: Mastering Search Filters](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/mastering-ldap-search-filters.html)
- [LDAP: Programming practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-programming-practices.html)

Answer (score 0):

I find the problem, the $ldaprdn = 'uid=test,dc=ci,dc=mycompany,dc=com' is not as same as it on LDAP server, after change it works well.

Comment: Hi can you detailed your answer it will helpful for me plz

Answer (score 0):

@Annamalai.Somasundaram,

DN should be passed something like **cn=test,ou=Users,dc=ci,dc=mycompany,dc=com**

the correct spelling can be found on the specific LDAP server